# Using concurrent map with multiple parameter lists in python

Tags: python

I try to parallelize my current code by using scoops map call.
I know how to apply it to basic functions.
My problem is that I would like to apply this map call to a function which has, for some parameters, a range of values.

My current code looks like follows:

```
paramA = True
paramB = 500
paramC = [1,2,3,4,5]
paramD = [0,2,4,6,8]

resultsA = []
resultsB = []

for x in paramC:
    for y in paramD:
        resultA, resultB = doFoo(a=paramA, b=paramB, c=x, d=y)
        resultsA.append(resultA)
        resultsB.append(resultB)
```

doFoo() is a CPU intensive task which I would like to parallelize to, at first, multiple cores or even multiple hosts.
What I would like to have in the end is something like this:

```
from scoop import futures

paramA = True
paramB = 500
paramC = [1,2,3,4,5]
paramD = [0,2,4,6,8]

resultsA, resultsB = futures.map(doFoo, (paramA, paramB, paramC, paramD))
```

Is that possible? What would be the pythonic way to achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards,
Robin

Comment: What problem do you face with this....

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic way of doing this would be to use [starmap](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) instead of map. Unfortunatly it doesn't look like scoop implements starmap, so instead you can wrap your doFoo function with a function that takes a single tuple of arguments, unpacks them, and passes them to doFoo.

```
def doFooStar(params):
    return doFoo(*params)

param_list = ((paramA, paramB, x, y) for x in paramC for y in paramD)

results = futures.map(doFooStar, param_list)
resultsA, resultsB = zip(*results)
```